# Linux - Get the start and end of the stack memory for a thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am trying to port something to Linux.
My original code (for a RTOS) looks like:

```cpp
int stackSize = 4*1024;
void* stack = malloc(stackSize);
int thread = create_thread(stack, FuncToRun)
```

Later the stack and stackSize are used by the garbage collector and to get some thread statistics.

Now, how do I convert the above code to Linux?

Comment: Use pthread_create with a non-null attribute argument.

Comment: I mean, normally you don't need to allocate the stack on Linux, the system does it automatically. But if you want to, the facility is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Pthread:

```
int stackSize = 4*1024;

pthread_attr_t atrib_thread;
pthread_attr_init(&atrib_thread);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&atrib_thread,stackSize);

pthread_t my_thread;
pthread_create(&my_thread,&atrib_thread,FuncToRun,NULL);
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_attr/

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_create/

Comment: So void* stack = malloc(stackSize); is replaced by stack = pthread_attr_getstackaddr(my_thread)? (so that I can find where the stack starts)

Comment: @Dragos You can get the address with that, but the argument is atrib_thread

Comment: Anyway, you don't need set StackSize in Linux, you can let System Defaults

Comment: If that Linux is running on my 64GB RAM PC, I can use the defaults; but it will run on a microcontroller with very limited resources, so I need to change the stack size depending on what that thread will run.